# Explanation of code result

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Can you explain to me why does the first element ot the 2 dimentional array is 1 in this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
   int main(void) {
       int i,j;
       int **p = (int **)malloc(2 * sizeof(int *));
       p[0] = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
       p[1] = p[0];
       for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
               for(j = 0; j < 2; j++){
                   printf("i=%d & j=%d\t",i,j);
                   p[i][j] = i + j;
                   printf("p[%d][%d]=%d\n",i,j,p[i][j]);
                   printf("this is the result of the first element %d\n",p[0][0]);
               }


       printf("this is the result %d\n",p[0][0]);
       return 0;
   }
```

The result is :

> i=0 & j=0       p[0][0]=0
>
> this is the result of the first element 0
>
> i=0 & j=1       p[0][1]=1
>
> this is the result of the first element 0
>
> i=1 & j=0       p[1][0]=1
>
> this is the result of the first element 1
>
> i=1 & j=1       p[1][1]=2
>
> this is the result of the first element 1
>
> this is the result 1
>
> Press  to close this window...

Comment: You intended `p[0]` and `p[1]` to refer to the *same* singular row?

Comment: Most likely not related to your problem, but [**do not cast the result of `malloc()`**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/3488231).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the two rows `p[0]` and `p[1]` are indeed the same.

`p` is an array of two pointers:

```
int **p = (int **)malloc(2 * sizeof(int *));
```

The first one points to an array of size 2:

```
p[0] = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
```

The second one points to the same array:

```
p[1] = p[0];
```

So any modification to `p[1][0]` will reflect on `p[0][0]`, since both refer to the same location in memory. As you can verify, you assigned `1` to `p[1][0]`, so `p[0][0]` becomes `1` too.

Comment: So p[1] = p[0]; this was the mistake it sould be a new malloc to get a 2 dimentional array i suppose

Answer (score 1):

I tried to explain in the figure ( sorry for that but its easier ).[image]

So to correct your mistake and to declare a proper 2-D matrix , in place of malloc for **p[0]** write `for(int i=0; i < 2;i++)p[i] = (int *)malloc(2*sizeof(int));`.